# spring.profiles.active not honoured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

In

```
application.properties
```

we have the line

```
spring.profiles.active=LOCALHOST
```

In

```
application-DEV.properties
```

, we have the line

```
spring.profiles.active=DEV,dbcache,metrics,AWS
```

. When running the app with

```
java -jar app.war -Dspring.profiles.active=DEV
```

the console output says

```
The following profiles are active: LOCALHOST
```

, ie the

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=DEV
```

argument isn't honored, the app still uses the default LOCALHOST profile.

Comment: What happens if you put the `-D` option in front of `-jar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My man page for the `java` command says:

```
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]
```

That is, JVM options (such as property settings) must go *before* the `-jar` (or main class). Anything after that is considered an argument passed to `main`.

This actually has a purpose and isn't just pedantic--you might have a tool that launches a child JVM (Maven can do this, for example) and want to provide arguments to be passed there.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case some one is having the same issue as me, make sure your main class args is passed into spring. Hope it helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Big thanks for adding that answer! That is indeed a pretty easy to miss source of the same end problem.

Comment: Yup, this question is currently top google hit when searching "spring.profiles.active not working". It's so easy to forget to do this, or drop it off when refactoring (that's how I got here >.<)

Comment: ths,That answer settled my question